# How to Show Pdf file pages like a listview in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, pdf, pdf-viewer

I have a pdf file Picked from file picker and
I want to display pdf file pages like a list view items.
On click page its show like page is selected and get page number that clicked
My Final input is look like:

[My Required Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVB4P.png)

Anyone help me Please

Comment: Please provide a code snippet what you have achieved so far

Answer (score 0):

Try this - https://pub.dev/packages/pdf_render#multi-page-view-using-listviewbuilder

Then you have to use `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,` for your ListView.
Also, wrap `PdfPageView` with your custom widget that will handle selection and render checkmark.

If you need a scrollbar, just wrap your ListView with `Scrollbar` widget and tune it. More info - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scrollbar-class.html